# Screenshot function does not work on other machines

Tags: python, ctypes, win32gui

I am trying to take window screenshot while the windows is in background. The code runs perfectly on my system(HP, win7). The same code fails to give proper output on another system(win7, Lenovo and Dell). It does give the screenshot, but it is not clear. There is black color wherever there is empty area in the window.
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw0Qf.png)

```
def capture_screen(win_name,outloc,imagename,h):
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None,win_name)
        # Get window bounds
        left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
        w = right - left
        #h = bot - top
        hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
        mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
        saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

        saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

        saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

        result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 1)
        #print(result)

        bmp_info = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
        bmp_str = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        #print(bmp_str)

        im = Image.frombuffer('RGB',(bmp_info['bmWidth'], bmp_info['bmHeight']),
            bmp_str, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

        win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
        saveDC.DeleteDC()
        mfcDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)

        if result == 1:
            im.save(outloc+imagename)
```

Comment: This code works only for native win32 applications, for example Notepad. Some applications like web browsers, or Windows 10 Calculator, are not native win32 and the screen shot of background window will fail. You have to bring the target window to the front and take screen shot of the whole desktop.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @BarmakShemirani. I was just wondering that how it worked on one system and not on the other.

Answer (score 0):

To capture any hidden window (Win32, UWP, ...), you can use DWM ([DwmRegisterThumbnail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmregisterthumbnail) )